# PHP: word check for 30 chars

Tags: php

I would like to check that if $_POST[msg] contains a word that are longer than 30 chars(without no spaces) so you wouldnt be able to write:

example1 :

asdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsddsasdsdsdsdsd

example2:
hello my name is asdoksdosdkokosdkosdkodskodskodksosdkosdkokodsdskosdkosdkodkoskosdkosdkosdkosdsdksdoksd

(notice no spaces).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) to look for that as follows...

```
if (preg_match('/\S{31,}/', $_POST['msg']))
{
     //string contains sequence of non-spaces > 30 chars
}
```

The /S matches any non-space character, and is the inverse of /s which matches any space. See the manual page on [PCRE escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: `[\S]` is pointless. You probably forgot to remove `[]` when changing from `[^\s]`

Comment: that's true - I'm personally in the habit of negating \s rather than using \S, but thought it would be more instructive to use \S - will edit

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex `\w{31,}` to find for a word that has 31 or more characters:

```
if(preg_match('/\w{31,}/',$_POST['msg'])) {
        echo 'Found a word >30 char in length';
}
```

If you want to find group of non-space characters that are 31 or more characters in length, you can use:

```
if(preg_match('/\S{31,}/',$_POST['msg'])) {
        echo 'Found a group of non-space characters >30 in length';
}
```

Comment: I like your answer better I think.

Answer (score 0):

First find the words:

```
// words are separated by space usually, add more logic here
$words = explode(' ', $_POST['msg']);

foreach($words as $word) {
    if(strlen($word) > 30) { // if the word is bigger than 30
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: for a string  with more than a few words, this is a pretty wasteful approach. PHP is going to all the trouble of building you an array which you don't really need. For longer strings, a regex or other approach which just linearly scans the string will be far more speed and space efficient.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Just difference in logic

```
if (strlen(preg_replace('#\s+#', '', $_POST['msg'])) > 30) {
    //string contain more then 30 length (spaces aren't counted)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First split the input into words:

```
explode(" ", $_POST['msg']);
```

then get the maximum length string:

```
max(explode(" ", $_POST['msg']));
```

and see if that is larger than 30:

```
strlen(max(explode(" ", $_POST['msg']))) > 30
```

Comment: No, I think the Python side of your brain is having a fight with the PHP side. Test your solution and you'll see what I mean.